# Home Page/Timeline/ Wall web page construction

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am having troubles loading data ordered by date from my database.

I created a database to hold the data(about 4 id's of users). On the time line page, the posts of the users above are supposed to be echo "relatively", Ordered by date.

But when i coded, the post of the first user is loaded first, ordered by date, the the second user, and so on....

Please how can i fix this?

Edited!

```
    $timeline = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM timeline_users") or die (mysql_error());
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($timeline)) {
                                $user = $row['id'];
                        $post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE userid = $user ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7") or die (mysql_error());
                                $p = mysql_fetch_array($post);


                                //post data
}
}
```

// and so on

Comment: please add your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to display the posts by order of date, and not by the user? The reason why the first user is loaded first is because of your first query it doesn't have any order so regardless of your order by date for your second query it will still get the first user as it was the first one loaded to your second query.

try this:

```
 $timeline = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM timeline_users") or die (mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($timeline)) {
     $user[] = $row['id'];
  }

  $newUsers = implode(",",$user);
  $post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE userid IN ($newUser) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7") or die (mysql_error());
  $p = mysql_fetch_array($post);
```

Comment: when i did that i got this mysql error... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7' at line 1

Comment: @adetiwa that would mean your $row['id'] is not returning anything, have you checked your first query if it does return the row id?